# Master Slave Replication in Mysql

Tags: mysql, replication

I have generated a dump from Master  and I have to construct slave and give privileges and binary log position and file name of master for it to obsorb from master. Master is a high transaction OLTP application having TPS of 74.21 inserts/s, 113.17 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 77468.29 reads/s. Now when DML operations are about to operate on SLAVE via binlogs would there be any impact on Master's performance. Say for example Load Avg or IO operations on Master that might get affected. As it allows slave to read the binlog info .

Note: Master and Slave have same server configuration.

Mysql Version : 5.0.77

OS : CentOS 5.4

Mem: 16GB RAM (80% allocated to INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE)

Database Size: 380 GB

This question strikes me when I wanted to scp some of the files to Slave. Whereas it has just 34MBPS avg speed within the network and it took reads IO operations a lot and Load Avg was hitting more than 6, 7 , 11 etc .. Ofcourse its not going to use SSH as it uses mysql socket to connect. Just a measurement to have slave in place by not hindering master's perf.

My questions are:

1. Could there be any load spiking in cpu processors or IO, that which can slow down Master Perf?
2. If any medium that I can trfr data that uses less cpu/IO utilization ?

Regards,

Mannoj Kumar

Comment: scp will burn CPU. FTP, rsync, rcp are unencrypted options. Or NFS mount one server to the other and copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is No.

In Mysql replication, Master copies the bin log files to slaves, and after that, it's work is over. Now the Slave will run the bin files and execute them, but there won't be any performance on Master.

There might be scenario where you are using full synchronous replication, in which master will wait for the slave to execute the query, but again it won't impact the performance in terms of memory or CPU, but the master will wait for the query to be executed.

Also, for your second question, Phil already answered it, that ssh sends data through encryption which uses a lot of CPU, hence if you want other ways, use the other methods which are described by Phil.